# How can I access record or frecord varibale in function result so that i can use it to function submit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have tried to make the record variable global and after that, I am trying to use it in submit function but it's giving an error 'record is not defined'. Can anyone help me to understand the situation?

Below I have two functions (`result` and `submit`), and the record variable is basically have some value in result which I want to access in submit. Can anyone help?

```
    def submit(): ## this function will use to add stock.
        for i in f_record:                           (SUBMIT FUNCTION )
            for j in i:
                if(j==name1.get()):
                    p=int(i[3]) * quantity1          
        price=p

    def result(): # This function will use to see if the stock is added or not. Also to see the present stock                                              (RESULT FUNCTION)
        stock=sqlite3.connect('Super Store Stock')
        c=stock.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM y')   ##this will use to select all elements from table we have created 
        global record
        record=c.fetchall()
        stock.commit()
        stock.close()
        return
```

Comment: There is no `record` anywhere in your `submit()` function. Please take a step back and first extract a [mcve] and read the documentation on globals in Python. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].